# Merge two columns in to one and then continue with two columns again in two columns container

Tags: html, css, angular

I am currently having an issue with styling my two column container, Below piece of code works perfectly for creating a two column grid. My new requirement is to have a horizontal line (`<hr>`) in between based on some condition.

Would be really helpful if anyone can help me out in solving this.

HTML:

```
    <div class="two-column-container" >
      <div *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index" >
        <div class="two-column-item">
          <div class="attribute-name">
            {{item.id}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
two-column-item {
     max-width: 375px;
     width: 100%;
     margin-top: 25px;
   }

two-column-container {
    @include columnar-flex();

    @include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
      min-width: 250px;
    }

    @include media-breakpoint-between(sm, md) {
      min-width: 500px;
    }

    @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
      min-width: 980px;
    }
  }
```

Existing output

[image: Existing output]

New Requirement

[image: New Requirement]

For the following code

```
        <div class="two-column-container" >
          <div *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index" >
            <div class="two-column-item">
              <div class="attribute-name">
                {{item.id}}
              </div>
              <div class="horizontal-line">
                <hr>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
horizontal-line {
             width: 100%;
             margin-top: 25px;
           }
```

the output is as shown below. I would like to have horizontal line in two columns.
[image]

Comment: How did you manage to break the line after item 3 so item 5 moved to a new line? (If I understand correctly, the only difference needed is the border..)

Comment: it happened because of div class two-column-item. Now I would like to add a horizontal line. Added more point in the question for better understanding.

Comment: I'm not sure I still get it. Although I'm not very familiar with Angular I can try to help, but I'll need you to create a codesandbox which represent this state. You don't need the whole app of course just the relevant parts..